# Touchpad doesn't work after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

Working with an Acer Aspire One (netbook).

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 via USB, and also ran Windows 10 updates, working with the mouse plugged in. After I unplugged the mouse later, the touchpad on my computer no longer works.

On Windows the device shows up as working, but it just doesn't register when I try to use it.

Like I said, I can't definitely pinpoint the action that caused it to break as the installation of Ubuntu. I created a partition for it, so I'm surprised that it doesn't work now on either of the operating systems. I'm going to continue debugging but does anyone have any ideas of what my have caused it / possible fixes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop has a function to turn off the touchpad, FN + F7. For some reason it's turned off by default on startup. However, we're working, so we're golden, that can be solved later.